# Formulario bootstrap inline en mobil

Tags: bootstrap-4

El problema que tengo es que cuando abro el formulario en el móvil, la label sale en un renglón y el input en otro. Esto no me es muy útil ya que me ocupa mucho espacio. Cuando lo ensancho un poco mas si que se ponen en el mismo renglón etiqueta e input.
He intentado col-xs-4 y col-xs-8 para etiqueta e input  a ver si así se ponen en una linea pero nada.

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-12  col-xs-12 ">
   <form>
       <div class="form-group row mb-0 ">
     <label  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Parte</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="parte" placeholder="Parte">
     </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2  col-form-label">Fecha</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 ">
     <div class="input-group date fecha" id="fechaP" data-target-input="nearest" >
        <div class="input-group-prepend" data-target="#fechaP" data-toggle="datetimepicker" >
       <div class="input-group-text " ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
       </div>
       <input type="text"  id="fecha" class="form-control  form-control-sm datetimepicker-input datetimepicker" placeholder="Fecha" data-target="#fechaP"/>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   
   <div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Hora Inicio</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <div class="input-group date hora" id="hInicioP" data-target-input="nearest" >
        <div class="input-group-prepend hora" data-target="#hInicioP" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
       <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
       </div>
       <input type="text" id="hInicio" class="form-control  form-control-sm datetimepicker-input  " placeholder="Hora Inicio" data-target="#hInicioP"/>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Hora Fin</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <div class="input-group date hora" id="hFinP" data-target-input="nearest" >
        <div class="input-group-prepend hora" data-target="#hFinP" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
       <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
       </div>
       <input type="text" id="hFin" class="form-control  form-control-sm datetimepicker-input  " placeholder="Hora Fin" data-target="#hFinP"/>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
     <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tipo Movimiento</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="tipMovimiento">
       
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
     <label for="inputOrigen" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label ">Origen</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm centro"  id="origen">
       
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
     <label for="inputDestino" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label ">Destino</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm centro" id="destino" >
       
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
     <label for="inputChofer" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Chofer</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm " id="chofer">
       <option>Chofer</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
     <label for="inputCamion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Camión</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm " id="camion">
       
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
     <label for="inputCamion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Observaciones</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="observaciones" rows="2"></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Acabo de ver en la web de bootstrap que hay que usar col- para los dispositivos mas pequeños. Siento haber preguntado sin investigar lo suficiente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente debes eliminar el xs (sufijo de col), debido a que en versiones posteriores de Bootstrap 4.x ya no se utiliza el sufijo **xs** (Extra small), en su caso solo sería col-[n].
Ejemplo:
`<div class="col-12">foo</div>`

Nota: Puede ver en más detalles: [Grid de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Retomando su código quedaría:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row mb-0 ">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Parte</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="parte" placeholder="Parte">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-2 col-form-label">Fecha</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <div class="input-group date fecha" id="fechaP" data-target-input="nearest">
            <div class="input-group-prepend" data-target="#fechaP" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="fecha" class="form-control  form-control-sm datetimepicker-input datetimepicker" placeholder="Fecha" data-target="#fechaP">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-2 col-form-label">Hora Inicio</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <div class="input-group date hora" id="hInicioP" data-target-input="nearest">
            <div class="input-group-prepend hora" data-target="#hInicioP" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="hInicio" class="form-control  form-control-sm datetimepicker-input  " placeholder="Hora Inicio" data-target="#hInicioP" />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-2 col-form-label">Hora Fin</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <div class="input-group date hora" id="hFinP" data-target-input="nearest">
            <div class="input-group-prepend hora" data-target="#hFinP" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="hFin" class="form-control  form-control-sm datetimepicker-input  " placeholder="Hora Fin" data-target="#hFinP" />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-2 col-form-label">Tipo Movimiento</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="tipMovimiento">

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="inputOrigen" class="col-2 col-form-label ">Origen</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm centro" id="origen">

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="inputDestino" class="col-2 col-form-label ">Destino</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm centro" id="destino">

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="inputChofer" class="col-2 col-form-label">Chofer</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm " id="chofer">
            <option>Chofer</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <label for="inputCamion" class="col-2 col-form-label">Camión</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm " id="camion">

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label for="inputCamion" class="col-2 col-form-label">Observaciones</label>
        <textarea class="col-10 form-control" id="observaciones" rows="2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```